# How to show one item from array in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

So im writting front-end for one simple app, and im stuck on one thing.
There is a news list page which should take user to single news page.

All news are in one array, which is sitting in the news controller:

```js
'use strict';

NaturaApp.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(value) {

});
$scope.categories = [{
tout: "tout",
produits: "produits"}];

var categories = {
tout: "tout",
produits: "produits"
};

$scope.newsOne = [{
id: '1',
categoryID: categories.tout,
name: 'One Lorem ipsum.',
thumb: 'http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature',
shot: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
cont: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi necessitatibus natus ullam.'},
{
id: '2',
categoryID: categories.tout,
name: 'Two Lorem ipsum.',
thumb: 'http://lorempixel.com/90/90/animals',
shot: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
cont: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit labore.'},
{
id: '3',
categoryID: categories.tout,
name: 'Three Lorem ipsum.',
thumb: 'http://lorempixel.com/90/90/abstract',
shot: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
cont: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id aliquid quidem obcaecati numquam nobis nam!'}];

$scope.newsTwo = [{
id: '1',
categoryID: categories.produits,
name: 'One CAT2 Lorem ipsum.',
thumb: 'http://lorempixel.com/90/90/sports',
shot: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
cont: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi necessitatibus natus ullam.'},
{
id: '2',
categoryID: categories.produits,
name: 'Two CAT2 Lorem ipsum.',
thumb: 'http://lorempixel.com/90/90/cats',
shot: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
cont: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit labore.'},
{
id: '3',
categoryID: categories.produits,
name: 'Three CAT2 Lorem ipsum.',
thumb: 'http://lorempixel.com/90/90/food',
shot: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
cont: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id aliquid quidem obcaecati numquam nobis nam!'}];
});
```

Here's news list page, working correctly:

```html
<ul class="list">
<li ng-repeat="newsOne in newsOne">
<a href="#/news/{{newsOne.id}}" data-transition="slide-in">
<span>
<img src="{{newsOne.thumb}}"/>
</span>
<span>
<b>{{newsOne.name}}</b><br>
{{newsOne.shot}}
</span>
<span class="chevron"></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And i dont have a clue to be honest how to make one single, selected news visible...

Comment: what you are trying to do is very similar to the tutorial on angular docs site. Go through the tutorial step by step... will help a lot  http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Woring plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3yV7WHVJFU5SCoNhnlAz?p=preview)

In your **route-config**:

```
NaturaApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider        
        .when('/news/', {
            templateUrl: 'news.html',
            controller: 'NewsCtrl',
        })      
        .when('/news/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'news-post.html',
            controller: 'NewsCtrl',
        });

}]);
```

**SchoolCtrl:**

```
NaturaApp.controller('NewsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    var listOfNews = [....];

    if($routeParams.id)
    {
       $scope.news = listOfNews[$routeParams.id];
    }
    else
    {
       $scope.news = listOfNews;
    }        

}]);
```

And in your views:
**news.html**:

```
<div ng-repeat="newspost in news">
   <h1>{{newspost.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

**news-post.html:**

```
<h1>{{newspost.title}}</h1>
<p>{{newspost.content}}</p>
```